# How can I open a pdf after I create that with iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I created a pdf with iText and I want to open it, but when I do that Adobe Reader says me "Error opening document. This file is already open or is used by another application".
How can I resolve?

This is my code (sorry for the Houston println exception ;)):

```
try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("c:/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/"+txtName.getText().toString()+".pdf"));
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("src/file.pdf");
            PdfStamper stamper =  new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("c:/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/"+txtName.getText().toString()+".pdf"));
            AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
            ..code..
            stamper.close();
            //document.close();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "c:/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/"+txtName.getText().toString()+".pdf");
                }catch (Exception exc) {
                    System.out.println("Houston we got a problem! : "+exc);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Where did you copy that example from and why aren't you using the most recent iText version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an old iText version. In the old days, we had `PdfWriter` to create documents from scratch and we had `PdfStamper` to manipulate existing documents.

It seems that you want to fill out a form, which requires `PdfStamper`, but for some mysterious reason you also use `PdfWriter` as if you want to create a new PDF from scratch.

If you insist on using that old iText version, you shoild drop a couple of lines:

```
try {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("src/file.pdf");
    PdfStamper stamper =  new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("c:/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/"+txtName.getText().toString()+".pdf"));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    ..code..
    stamper.close();
}
```

In the old iText, there's really no reason for you to use the `Document` and `PdfWriter` class for form filling.

To avoid the confusion you're in, we rewrote iText from scratch, and we released this rewrite about 2 years ago. It's amazing to see that you chose an old version being new at iText. Moreover: iText 5 is no longer supported, so why not use iText 7?

Please read the iText 7 jump-start tutorial to see how form filling is done today: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-4-making-pdf-interactive

Comment: Hi Bruno. I understand what are you saying, can you say me where can I download itext7 libraries?

Comment: See the [iText 7 for Java](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java) on the official web site. Preference is given to using Maven; if you need the jars (which is really old school), you can get a ZIP from [github](https://github.com/itext/itext7).